# Does forward model selection by $R^2$ or SSR differ?

Tags: multiple-regression, python, feature-selection, r-squared, sums-of-squares

I'm trying to implement *forward selection* and need to add a feature only if it will make the sum of squared residuals ([SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares)) lower.

I am using Python's [`statsmodels`](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) OLS. My question is: can I use the $R^2$ from the `summary` for this? Or should I use something else?

Comment: Maximization of $R^2$ is the same as minimization of SSE.

Comment: $R^2_{adj} = 1 - (1-R^2) \frac{n-1}{n-k-1}$ is some way to incorporate the number of selected features $k$ in the coefficient of determination and it could be used for comparing models in feature selection. There are other criterions possible, such as aic and bic. If you wish to know more about this with relation to your problem then you should post a (new) question specific to your problem and ask what would be a good/best criterium for feature selection (or possibly it is already answered somewhere in an existing question  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=adjusted+R+aic).

Comment: Please change the title of your question. Your question is if the criteria $R^2$ and the Sum of Squared Residuals select the same models in forward selection; not if they’re identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No SSE is the sum of squared errors.

$R^2$ is *$\frac{SSR}{SSR+SSE}$* the ratio of sum of squares due to regression divided by the total sum of squares which equals *SSR+SSE*.

Comment: How would I go about getting it then?

Comment: After you calculate the least squares estimates of the regression parameters you can compute for each data point the difference between the observed value of the dependent variable and its estimated value, then square those values and sum them. That gives you SSE subtract that from the total sum of squares SST to get SSR.